# Pointer object Creates a windows error in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: windows, visual-c++-6

I will paste a code snippet and explain the problem I am facing,

```
void materialPropertiesDlg::OnNext() {
    contiBeam *continousBeamPtr;
    contiBeam contiBeamObj;
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    switch (m_steel_grade) {
        // Do Something
    }   
    continousBeamPtr->setMaterial(m_conc_grade, m_steel_grade);
    OnOK();
}
```

As you see, in line 2 a pointer object is created and in the next line an object is created. So, then I call the member function `setMaterials()` of the class `contiBeam`. I can easily do that with the object `contiBeamObj`, but when I call the function using `contiBeamPointer`, the windows throws an error which reads

> Application Has Stopped working.

I am able to do the needful, I just want to know what could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your pointer `contiBeam *continousBeamPtr;`  without having allocated it.

That is **Undefined Behaviour** and will make your application crash.

You should allocate (reserve memory for) your pointer by using `new`, like so:

```
 contiBeam *continousBeamPtr = new contiBeam;
```

However, the ultimate question is, *why* are you using a pointer in the first place? Do you need one? Doesn't look like it from the code you posted.

Comment: Actually, I am new to Visual C++ and programming, I learn by trying different things. Also, I would like to know how does using `new` help? What is its role?

Comment: The Solution you provided did not work, the statement that worked is `contiBeam *continousBeamPtr = new contiBeam;`

Comment: @vin sorry, my mistake.  It should indeed be the type after the `new`.  `new` allocated memory for an object on the heap and returns a pointer to that memory.